# How to get the index of the three highest int's of an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to get an array with the 3 biggest scores. I tried this but it doesn't work the way it's supposed to. Can somebody help me, please?

```
public int getScore(int teamnumber) { // scores = [100, 25, 55, 15, 17]
    return this.scores[teamnumber-1];
}
public int[] top3() {
    int[] copy = scores;
    int[] out = new int[3];
    int max = 0;
    int biggest = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i != 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j != copy.length + 1; j++) {
            if (max < getScore(j)) {
                out[i - 1] = j;
                max = getScore(j);
                biggest = j;
            }
        }
        copy[biggest] = 0;
        max = 0;
    }
    return out; // returns [1,1,0]
}
```

Comment: Just to ask: Is sorting the array not an option here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int[] top3(int arr[]) { 
        int [] top = new int[3];
        int first, second, third; 

        third = first = second = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
            if (arr[i] > first) { 
                third = second; 
                second = first; 
                first = arr[i]; 
            } 
            else if (arr[i] > second) { 
                third = second; 
                second = arr[i]; 
            } 
            else if (arr[i] > third) 
                third = arr[i]; 
        } 
        top[0] =first; 
        top[1] = second; 
        top[2] = third;
        
        return top;    
    }
```

Then in main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {5,8,2,3,6};
        int[] top3 = top3(arr); 
        
        for(int i = 0; i < top3.length; i++){
         System.out.println(i+1 + " = " + top3[i]);
        }
        
    }
```

Of course this is not the most efficient way to solve this problem. The best approach would be to sort the array and retrieve the last 3 elements if sorted in ascending order.

Comment: Actually, I am pretty sure that this is the most efficient, since sorting the array would have time complexity of O(nlogn), while this method that you posted here has time complexity of O(n), which is faster for bigger and bigger arrays. Of course, sorting the array would be faster to type out!

Answer (score 0):

Check this one out....

Imports:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Code:

```
public int[] top3(int[] arr) {

        int ranking_slots = 3; 
        int [] ranking = new int[ranking_slots];

        Arrays.sort(arr, Collections.reverseOrder());

        for(int pos = 0; pos < ranking_slots; pos++){
        ranking[pos] = arr[pos];
        }
     return ranking;
     }
```